# meaning of this regex expression

Tags: regex

Can anybody tell me what does this regular expression identifies : `(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)` and `(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one :

```
"
(?!         # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   [^&;]       # Match a single character NOT present in the list “&;”
      +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ;           # Match the character “;” literally
)
(?!         # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   <           # Match the character “<” literally
   [^<>]       # Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>”
      *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
"
```

Second one :

```
"
(?!         # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   [^<>]       # Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>”
      *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   >           # Match the character “>” literally
)
(?!         # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   [^&;]       # Match a single character NOT present in the list “&;”
      +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ;           # Match the character “;” literally
)
"
```

Note that both of those expressions do not actually capture anything at all but they are probably used to pinpoint a position inside the string. Without any context is hard to tell exactly where they are used.

Comment: @FailedDev you sir, are a genius.  Do you have some application that you use to help parse it, or are you just a regex guru?

Comment: @Daryl No I am not a genius, yes I have an application. Expresso/regexbuddy to name a few.